# Enterprise Keywords in a document library

Tags: 2013, document-library, tags, enterprise-keywords

I am a beginner using SharePoint for my school and have been trying to use Enterprise Keywords in document libraries.  I have one site that I use for one year group.  There are many different pages that show this document library. Is there a way that I can automatically insert a tag/enterprise keyword on the different pages. I am looking for the tags to match that specific page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no OOTB feature available to tag the pages automatically. You need to write your own logic on itemupdating event which involved Object model based coding. Pls refer the below link to understand this [Reference Link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11044/onpublish-and-onunpublish-equivalent-events)